# Can we use package "dplyr" on R base 3.0.2?

Tags: data-mining

Is there any way to use package `dplyr` on RStudio having R base 3.0.2 ?

I am not interested in `plyr` package.

Comment: Questions about installing R packages aren't about Data Science and so aren't on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

dplyr 0.3 requires R 3.1+. If you're stuck on R 3.0.x, you have to use dplyr 0.2.x.